# How to dynamically update data of line chart used with chart Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

i am trying to update data in line chart created using chart js

on click of the buttons.

Please take a look at the js fiddle - `https://jsfiddle.net/w8zbjvgo/21/`
Here when i toggle between the week & month the data should update in same chart but its not working right now.

```
Is their any way to make it work ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle there are a couple of things that need to be corrected:

First - you're declaring a new set of data in your if statement and then not assigning it to the chart.

Second - you're not updating the chart.

Try this code:

```
let revisedViewsdata = "4,3,2,1,0,1,2";
myChart.data.datasets[0].data = revisedViewsdata;
myChart.update();
```

Comment: is their any way i can do that in php code like embed js code in php code ?

Comment: Put it in the if statement - in the button click event:   if ($(this).attr('data-text') == "week") { --new code here--} that will fire the three relevant lines if the week button is pressed

Comment: it says myChart is not defined

Comment: You must be using a different version of the code to what you posted

Comment: myChart.update();
this does the work, i need to put it in ajax success function.